# Dotnet.Highcharts error in export image

Tags: asp.net, .net, graph, charts, highcharts

I am using ASP.NET MVC website using Highcharts for graph,
when i use export image as PNG,JPEG,... export looks like this
[image]

With this labels cut in image, when should looks like is showing in website
[image]

I've tryed to set .SetExporting with different properties, but no success
This is my code

```
var chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = String.Empty })
            .SetCredits(new Credits { Enabled = false })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y; }" })
            //.SetExporting(new Exporting() { Width = 2000, Enabled = true, Filename = "Teste" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage.toFixed(2) +' %'; }"
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Name = String.Empty,
                Data = new Data((from o in data
                                 select new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point
                                 {
                                     Name = o.Key.Name,
                                     Y = o.count
                                 }).ToArray())
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is general problem with phantomJS, which should be fixed in the version 2.0. We need to wait until official release and then we update our servers. Related topic is available [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3649)

Comment: Thanks for answer, please when you see something about this update let me know. I will post here when i know something too :)

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the highcharts api, but i set the scale option to "1" for the "exporting" module in this way:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    ...
    exporting: {
        scale: 1,
    }
    ...
});
```

and that solved the problem.